# Pytest & Google App Engine Testbed: Validation Error causes test to Fail Despite Being Expected?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.9, ndb

I'm running into a weird error with pytest (version 7.4.2). I am writing some unit tests, including some that expect exceptions. In particular, I have this test that expects a validation error when you try to put() the record:

```
class TestMyModel:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("value", [-7, -1, 0])
    def test_non_positive_value_validation_error(self, value):
        from models.datastore import MyModel
        from google.appengine.ext import ndb

        m = MyModel(
            _just_created=True,  
            value=value
            )
        
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            m.put()
```

Now, as expected, `m.put()` is raising an exception. However, for some reason this error is causing the test to fail?!

> FAILED src/models/datastore/test/test_my_model.py::TestMyModel::test_non_positive_value_validation_error[-7] - ValueError: IntegerProp(b'value', validator=<function MyModel.validate_value at 0x7fd44c257280>) must be a positive integer!

On the other hand, if I pass in a positive integer value, then the test fails because an exception was not thrown (as expected):

> FAILED src/models/datastore/test/test_pick_bins.py::TestPickBins::test_non_positive_bin_num_validation_error[1] - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>

I've been searching around online, but no luck. At a loss for why this is happening. I also found that I get the same results if I use `p = m.put_async()` and never call `p.get_result()`...

For my unit tests, I have configured the testbed via an autouse fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def gae_testbed(request):
    from google.appengine.ext import testbed

    print('Activating gae_testbed...')

    tb = testbed.Testbed()
    tb.activate()
    tb.init_all_stubs()

    print ("gae_testbed initialized!")

    def teardown():
        print('Deactivating GAE stubs...')
        tb.deactivate()
        print('GAE stubs Deactived!')

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return tb
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I believe the exception happens when you create the entity and not when you do the put.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks you :) I’m new to both Python and this Google App Engine framework and was pulling my hair out over this, lolz. If you submit an answer I’ll accept it as the solution.

Comment: Ryan, glad to help!

Comment: A style point, you generally want all your imports at the top of the file and not inside functions.

Comment: For the moment, I'm trying to follow the pattern in the existing code. Also, I think for the purpose of unit tests - where some mocking may occur - it maybe useful to import certain dependencies on a per-test function basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception happens when you create the entity and not when you do the put.

Wrapping the entity creation in `pytest.raises()` should fix it for you.